# How to represent nested widgets in Qt designer in code (PyQt5)?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

After I finished designing the interface with Qt designer, I planned to use Python Pyqt5 in VS code to find parts in the interface for further design, but I did not know how to represent this part in code.

[image]

[image]

Why does the above code not represent the part I need (account_lineEidt)

Report an error

AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'account_Layout'

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic


class MyWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("./login_interface.ui")

        self.user_name_qwidget = self.ui.layout.widget.account_Layout.account_lineEidt 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MyWindow()
    # 展示窗口
    w.ui.show()

    app.exec()
```

Comment: It's just `self.ui.account_lineEdit` (pay more attention, it's not `Eidt`). Widget references are always created as direct members of the ui object: in your case, `self.ui.layout`, `self.ui.widget`, etc. Also, please don't post in other languages other than English, and [avoid using images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0):

I redesigned the interface again and found that the original Dialog had nested a layout, and the layout was nested with other layouts, but the Dialog could have added layouts, which meant I added useless layouts, which caused me to get an error even when I used self.ui.account_lineEdit.
So I removed the "layout" and ran it successfully with self.ui.account_lineEdit

Thanks to the experts for their answers！